# Create everyday trigger

Tags: mysql

How to create everyday trigger which will automatically do this query?

```sql
insert into deliverability.test_month (type,from_sale)
select type,from_sale
from deliverability.delivery_money_repo
where total = 100
```

Comment: schedule a job scheduler with daily scheduling  your stored procedure :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a stored procedure with the code within and call it like the below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Daily_Insertion
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into deliverability.test_month (type,from_sale)
    select type,from_sale
    from deliverability.delivery_money_repo
    where total = 100

END
```

Then set it to run daily

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    DO
      CALL Daily_Insertion
```

Comment: could you show how to set concrete time `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY`

Comment: my  ide navicat .

Comment: @stand, as per checked navicat has option to set schedule button or perhaps right clicking the stored procedure.